# Tell me how to round the button so that it looks like in the picture

Tags: css, button, border, border-radius

I have a problem, I don’t understand how to make a custom border for a button. I'm familiar with the border-radius property, but I don't understand how a button can be bent like that.

[image]

This is a picture of the button, how it should look by design.

Comment: It's better to use SVG in this case.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this cannot be solved using CSS?

Comment: I have never seen this done with CSS. It might be possible in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to add svg via background-image

Comment: If it's of any help, there's this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1w59L8b7/), that might help you discover the shape you're after. Good luck (but SVG is still, almost certainly, the better option).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do this with the CSS property **border-radius**

You can make this type of button using

```
border-bottom-left-radius: __px;
border-bottom-right-radius: __px;
```

and like so

you have to hit and trail for the border radius property

You can also visit the MDN for further info on this topic

[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)